# Android Title overlay's actionbar content

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an application that uses localisation and in some of the languages, the title is to long for the size of the screen. I want to scale the title if it doesn't fit correctly in the space it has to a smaller font size. I use a custom xml file for the title bar but cannot figure out how to scale the font size depending on if it fits or not. Looking into this, it seems I need a lot of code for quite a small feature, can anyone help me resolve this please! My custom title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/title_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="title" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/Hearing_Test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/info_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:onClick="infoView"
    android:src="@drawable/info"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue I've got is that the text goes behind the image button, but also goes onto two line so the user can only see half of the second line. If someone could show me an example, of send me a link to somewhere that can help, that would be brilliant. Thanks

**Edit:**

Just to add to this, On newer phones such as the nexus 5, the menu is in the top right corner and from what I've read, I cannot find the width of this button, so I'm a bit stuck to how I can go about finding the width of everything in the custom title bar!

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your textview text size according to the Device screen and text length [Note: If text will be too long it will nearly not readable. Use length limit and show ... after it.], Never mind, the way is.

Calculate your Device display size and find out the scale factor, than apply the following code to resize the textview text size.

```
float size = textview.getTextSize();
                float factor = scalefactor;
                float product = size*factor;
                textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);
                size = textview.getTextSize();
```

Hope will help you out.

Comment: This looks perfect! How would I go about finding out the scale factor though?

Comment: `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float scaleFactor = metrics.density;`.

Comment: brill, I'll implement this now and let you know how it goes, Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Hi, so this made my text massive and I couldn't see any of it lol. I have just found that I can add a dimens xml file to each value folder, which will allow me to specify the font size depending on the localisation though, so I'm temped to use this. Why do you think it didnt scale my text correctly?

Comment: It is, But you have to divide the whole product [float product = size*factor;] with your text length or have to apply some math which will get you the correct size.

Comment: ahhh ok I'm with you! I was just thinking also, when it is too big, it  goes behind the imageButton, how can I stop it doing this?

Comment: I think for the titles and the buttons, too long text is not preferable to use, and if it's necessary than display the text with ..., and as soon as user long pressed there will show the hover notification with full length text, that's what ActionBar does do.